# JavaScript Console Disabled in Visual Studio 2013 (Node, TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have created a new Visual Studio project using a template (Basic Node.js Express 3 Application) from Node Tools for Visual Studio. I am able to debug without any issues. However, the menu selection for the JavaScript Console is disabled during debugging. How can I re-enable the JavaScript Console?

[image: Visual Studio 2013 menu selections during debugging session]

Comment: Does the Immediate Window not work for you to debug in JavaScript?

Comment: The JavaScript Console has many additional features beyond the Immediate Window. Such as the ability to drill down into objects.